# gcc 4.9.2 bug in -Werror=sizeof-pointer-memaccess?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

```
#include <string.h>

void test(char charArray [100])
{
    strncpy(charArray, "some text", sizeof(charArray));
}

int main()
{
    char charArray [100];
    test(charArray);
    // EDIT: According to comment from P0W I added this line - where is the difference?
    strncpy(charArray, "some text", sizeof(charArray)); // compiles OK
}
```

Compiled with gcc 4.9.2 on SLES 11 SP2 with this command line `g++ gcc-warning-bug-2.cpp -Wall -Wextra -c -Werror` I get this warning. Due the `-Werror` flag I cannot compile the project:

```
gcc-warning-bug-2.cpp: In function ‘void test(char*)’:
gcc-warning-bug-2.cpp:5:40: error: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’ call is the same expression as the destination; did you mean to provide an explicit length? [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-memaccess]
  strncpy(charArray, "some text", sizeof(charArray));
                                        ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

According to the actual gcc 4.9.2 documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

```
-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess
Warn for suspicious length parameters to certain string and memory built-in functions if the argument uses sizeof.
This warning warns e.g. about memset (ptr, 0, sizeof (ptr)); if ptr is not an array, but a pointer, and suggests a possible fix, or about memcpy (&foo, ptr, sizeof (&foo));. This warning is enabled by -Wall.
```

this should be compiled fine because `charArray` is an array!

Bug? Should I report it to GNU gcc developer team?

Comment: `'charArray'` is a pointer, array decays to pointer when passed as argument to function. `sizeof` here is giving size of pointer `char*`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You fell straight into the trap.

In C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, a parameter with a declaration that looks like "array of T" actually has type T*.

Your parameter charArray has a declaration that looks like "array of 100 chars", but the declaration is in fact "pointer to char".

Therefore, your third parameter to strncpy has a value of (most likely) 4 or 8, and not the 100 that you seem to expecct.

BTW. strncpy is highly dangerous the way you use it.

Comment: OK. This is for me an explanation. 1) But can I fix it? 2 )Why is strncpy using it this way very dangerous? Is it because I do not consider the finishing `0x00`?

Comment: OMG. Yes, I tried it now without the `-Wall` option and it copied indeed only 8 bytes - the size of a pointer in my Linux environment! THANK YOU! There is really a reason to use the `-Wall -Wextra` switches. They can safe you lot of hours of looking for a bug! As the only one solution I see for me I have to provide to the function with the parameter `charArray` also the size and considering the terminating `0x00`

Comment: @PeterVARGA Consider using libbsd's [`strlcpy()`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libbsd/tree/src/strlcpy.c)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Thank you for your comment but the question was asked more than 5 years ago and now I am using `gcc 9.3` and this is already a total different world.